# how to do hover/hide radio buttons using jquery while mouse hover on another radio button or its label, php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hover

When the user is hovering on a radio button/its label i want to display another radio button, that user can also select but if mouse moves the 2nd radio button hides again. i have found this last jquery snipet that shows choices while hovering on link tag

http://www.stylesfirst.com/coding/easy-show-hide-with-jquery/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p.trigger {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    background: url(plusminus.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}
p.trigger a {
    color: #474747;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
p.trigger a:hover {
    color: #ff4b43;
}
p.active {
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.toggle_container {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
.toggle_container .block {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.toggle_container').hide();
     jQuery('p.trigger').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="trigger"><a>Click here</a></p>
<div class="toggle_container">
  <div class="block">
     <input id='element_1_1' name='element_1' class='element radio' type='radio' value='8'/>
   <label class='choice' for='element_1_1'>Somewhere in the middle</label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as a user this sounds like an annoying unintuitive interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/HezZa/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer would be, if you could afford it, put both `<input type="radio"/>`s under a `<div/>` and control hovering behavior on that `<div/>`. This is commonly done with menus for the very same purpose.

Plus if you target new browsers, you can leave jQuery out of this - it can be done with any browser that understands the `:hover` pseudo-class on non-`<a/>`s.

Here's a sample page demonstrating both options.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#radios').hover(
                    function() { $('#radios').addClass('hover'); }, 
                    function() { $('#radios').removeClass('hover'); }
                    );
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* option 1 - jquery + css, for older browsers */
            #div-radio2 {
                display: none;
            }
            .hover #div-radio2 {
                display: block;
            }
            /* option 2 - no jquery, plain css, if you target only new browsers */
            #radios:hover #div-radio2 {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="radios">
            <div id="div-radio1"><input type="radio" id="radio1" /><label for="radio1">Radio 1</label></div>
            <div id="div-radio2"><input type="radio" id="radio2" /><label for="radio2">Radio 2</label></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```